# FFMPEG+video+video.js dont show up the video

Tags: video, drupal-7, ffmpeg, video.js

I have a video content type where I want to show the video to the user. I downloaded video module and video.js for this purpose. I have successfully installed ffmpeg transcoder in apache serv[image]

Now I go to admin/config/media/video. Withing players tab I select HTML5 player for mp4 video and video.js to run HTML5 video like below:-

[image]

Now I go to Video Content Type and add Video field with Video Upload as its type and save it.The video is successfully converted but after clicking on play button nothing happens.

[image]

Need your help in this.